# Add SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS via XcodeGen

Tags: xcode

Goal: I want to add `Xcode Target Build Settings - Active Compilation Conditions` via XcodeGen.

Is there any soultion to achieve this?

I've tried to add this code into `project.yml` file but didn't work.

```
targets:
  ...
  configs:
    Debug:
      SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS: DEBUG
    PreRelease:
      SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS: PRERELEASE
    Release:
      SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS: RELEASE
```

And my desired result is this image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhKbW.png)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What is this snippet you attached? The question lacks crucial information and can't be answered as it is now.

Comment: @lazarevzubov Sorry for that. I've just added more information about the question.

Comment: Yeh this actually has enough information to reproduce the issue.